# OpenGL GL_RGB texture format isn't working on iOS (GL_RGBA works great)

Tags: ios, opengl-es, textures

Hello people of the wasteland :),

Brief: There is a problem with GL_RGB internal texture format on iOS platform.

In my application I try to save some memory by using GL_RGB instead of GL_RGBA as an internal format.
I'm using the next code piece to achieve this. Nothing else is changed.

```
glTexImage2D(_textureTargetType, 
     0, 
     GL_RGB,            // pixel internalFormat
     texWidth,          // image width
     texHeight,         // image height
     0,             // border
     GL_RGBA,           // pixel format
     GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,      // pixel data type
     bitmapData);
```

On MacOS these changes went fluently, no problems. But on iOS, particularly 4.3 (OpenGL ES2.0) it gives me GL_INVALID_OPERATION everytime I try to render textured polgons with this texture. As nothing except this format is changed I think the problem is in incompatibility of GL_RGB internal format with OpenGL ES2.0. This is just my guess, I'm no guru.

This doesn't work in simulator nor iPod touch 4th gen.

Thank you for any reasonable suggestion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the documentation, "`internalformat` must match `format`. No conversion between formats is supported during texture image processing." See [the Khronos website](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexImage2D.xml). OpenGL does not have this limitation, so this code will work on Mac OS, but not the more limited OpenGL ES on iOS devices.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, it really is a solution :). I should read Khronos docs more carefully remembering that there may be a significant differences like this.